# Convertir entero de 10 dígitos a formato de fecha MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, date

Tengo una base de datos que almacena fechas pero las muestra con número a 10 dígitos:

```
1575205200
```

Ya revise unas respuestas del grupo la cual indica que utilice:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1575205200, '19700101')
```

Pero al momento de intentar correrlo en *PHPMYADMIN* me sale un error que dice que la función no existe, espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Esa es una función de SQL Server, por eso no funciona en MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa es una función de SQL Server, por eso no funciona en MySQL. La función correcta para MySQL es [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

La expresión quedaría así:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( '1970-01-01', INTERVAL 1575205200 SECOND)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, este me funciono correctamente, te agradezco la info y también que me aclararas lo anterior. Saludos.